# Django Test: how to simulate LookupError for django_apps.get_model()

Tags: django, django-models, django-tests, django-apps

I need help to implement a test for my Django app.
This is a snippet code from my serializer, that I want to test:

```
        try:
            app_config = django_apps.get_app_config(BcConfig.name)
            app_model = django_apps.get_model(app_label=app_config.name,
                                              model_name=type_model_name)
            recording = app_model.objects.create(**recording)
        except LookupError:
            recording = None
```

as mentioned in Django [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/applications/#django.apps.apps.get_model), Raises LookupError if no such application or model exists.

How to simulate the LookupError programmatically?

I have tried to remove the listed model using [ContentType](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/contenttypes/#django.contrib.contenttypes.models.ContentType), but django_apps.get_model() was still working.
I have tried to remove the model using [SchemaEditor](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/schema-editor/), but not working properly for testing in SQLite.
I also checked the DeleteModel() at [Migration Operations](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/5.0/ref/migration-operations/#deletemodel).

I still can not find how to delete the model or disable the Django app programmatically. I appreciate the help. Thank you.

Comment: You just use an `app_config` and `type_model_name` combination that does not point to a valid model?

Comment: I want to simulate if someone else using my code but not fully migrate the migration. so instead of change the code to use dummy app name or model name, I want to simulate if the model is not ready.

Comment: use something like `MyModel.objects.first()` and wrap it in a `try`-`except` with an `IntegrityError`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After getting [a clue](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77711049/3991504) regarding "testing these properly is the job of Django developers", I checked how Django [tests the apps](https://github.com/django/django/blob/4.2/tests/apps/tests.py).

I found that there's a testing tool to [override settings](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/testing/tools/#overriding-settings).
So currently, my solution is to add the test method with decorator `@override_settings(INSTALLED_APPS=LIST_WITHOUT_MY_APP)`. Then it triggered the LookupError exception as I expected.

See more detail in the Django [apps tests sample](https://github.com/django/django/blob/879e5d587b84e6fc961829611999431778eb9f6a/tests/apps/tests.py#L141C5-L149C10).

hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

> I have tried to remove the listed model using `ContentType`, but `django_apps.get_model()` was still working. I have tried to remove the model using `SchemaEditor`, but not working properly for testing in SQLite.

It does not *look* at databases. The `django_apps` dictionary only looks what models registered when starting to run the server. So these models don't per see have a corresponding table in the database.

If you want to test this, you can just pass non-sensical values, like:

```
type_model_name = 'my_non_existing_model_name'
try:
    app_config = django_apps.get_app_config(BcConfig.name)
    app_model = django_apps.get_model(
        app_label=app_config.name, model_name=type_model_name
    )
    recording = app_model.objects.create(**recording)
except LookupError:
    recording = None
```

But that being said, it often makes not much sense to test Django's features: testing these properly is the job of the Django developers, not of people building apps for Django. Their job is to test features that they have built on top of Django.

Comment: thank you. i understand your PoV. I just looking for other alternatives. I want to simulate if someone else using my code but not fully do the migrations. so instead of change the code to use invalid app name or model name, I want to simulate if the model is not ready.

Comment: @oonarfiandwi: what do you mean with "not ready". The apps are loaded in the order of the `INSTALLED_APPS`, it looks for `models.py` and registers the models that it is loading. If you would do querying in between, it is possible that these are not ready, but it looks like a bad idea to do eagerly some querying during the loading process.

Comment: what if even though the app registered on `INSTALLED_APPS`, and the Model has been written in `models.py`, but the developer that use my code, didn't do the migrations? (or at least the migrations is not fully applied).

Comment: @oonarfiandwi: you can check with `MyModel.objects.first()` and wrap it in a `try`-`except` and look for an `IntegrityError`. If the table does not exists, it will return a database error.